# Map reversed dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dict:

```
gameweek = {
    'Ceará':'Fortaleza', 'Fluminense': 'Atlético-GO', 
    'Goiás': 'Corinthians','Botafogo': 'Coritiba', 
    'Bahia': 'Flamengo','Athlético-PR': 'Bragantino',
    'Palmeiras': 'Internacional', 'Santos': 'Vasco',
    'Grêmio': 'Sport', 'Atlético-MG': 'São Paulo'}
```

an this `df`:

```
           team  
0    Atlético-MG                            
2         Grêmio                              
6         Santos                           
7          Bahia                                
8          Ceará                      
10         Goiás                            
12     Palmeiras                          
13    Fluminense                            
16      Botafogo                               
19  Athlético-PR
```

If I want to create a column for the adversary, I can do:

```
df['adversary']= df['team'].map(gameweek)
```

it works:

```
           team  adversary
0    Atlético-MG  São Paulo               
2         Grêmio  Sport                
6         Santos  Vasco              
7          Bahia  Flamengo                 
8          Ceará  Fortaleza          
10         Goiás  Corinthians           
12     Palmeiras  Internacional       
13    Fluminense  Atlético-GO          
16      Botafogo  Coritiba                  
19  Athlético-PR  Bragantino
```

---

But if I want to do the opposite, starting the df with dict values:

```
     team  
0    Vasco                           
2    Flamengo                              
6    Internacional                           
7    Corinthians                                
8    São Paulo                      
10   Fortaleza                            
12   Coritiba                          
13   Bragantino                            
16   Sport                               
19   Atlético-GO
```

The following does not work:

```
df['adversary']= df['team'].map(gameweek)
```

Returns `NaN`

Not if I reverse dict values, like so:

```
df['adversary']= df['team'].map({k: k for k, v in gameweek.items()})
```

Returns `NaN`

and finally this:

```
df['adversary']= df['team'].map({v: v for k, v in gameweek.items()})
```

Maps dict values to itself.

---

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try:

```
# note the v:k here
df['adversary']= df['team'].map({v: k for k, v in gameweek.items()})
```

Output:

```
             team     adversary
0           Vasco        Santos
2        Flamengo         Bahia
6   Internacional     Palmeiras
7     Corinthians         Goiás
8       São Paulo   Atlético-MG
10      Fortaleza         Ceará
12       Coritiba      Botafogo
13     Bragantino  Athlético-PR
16          Sport        Grêmio
19    Atlético-GO    Fluminense
```